# java user input assigned to variable can't be an integer to be divided?

Tags: java, variables, math

So I can't get the variables to be divisible, I need to be able to do this, otherwise I don't know of a way to finish building the lock that I want to build.

It uses 20 inputted numbers, and then arranges them into a Algebra2/calculus system of equations, and then solves for the "s", "a", "f", and "e" it starts by removing "e" from the equation by substituting.

I would greatly appreciate help, I'm open to ideas as well, because sofar I have 25 of these to build, and this is only 1/3 of the first one.

In short, how do I divide variables?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Lock
  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

   String num_a;
   System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
   num_a = user_input.next();

   String num_b;
   System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
   num_b = user_input.next();

   String num_c;
   System.out.print("Enter the third number: ");
   num_c = user_input.next();

   String num_d;
   System.out.print("Enter the fourth number: ");
   num_d = user_input.next();

   String num_e;
   System.out.print("Enter the fifth number: ");
   num_e = user_input.next();

   String num_f;
   System.out.print("Enter the sixth number: ");
   num_f = user_input.next();

   String num_g;
   System.out.print("Enter the seventh number: ");
   num_g = user_input.next();

   String num_h;
   System.out.print("Enter the eigth number: ");
   num_h = user_input.next();

   String num_i;
   System.out.print("Enter the ninth number: ");
   num_i = user_input.next();

   String num_j;
   System.out.print("Enter the tenth number: ");
   num_j = user_input.next();

   String num_k;
   System.out.print("Enter the eleventh number: ");
   num_k = user_input.next();

   String num_l;
   System.out.print("Enter the twetlth number: ");
   num_l = user_input.next();

   String num_m;
   System.out.print("Enter the thirteenth number: ");
   num_m = user_input.next();

   String num_n;
   System.out.print("Enter the fourteenth number: ");
   num_n = user_input.next();

   String num_o;
   System.out.print("Enter the fifteenth number: ");
   num_o = user_input.next();

   String num_p;
   System.out.print("Enter the sixteenth number: ");
   num_p = user_input.next();

   String num_q;
   System.out.print("Enter the seventeenth number: ");
   num_q = user_input.next();

   String num_r;
   System.out.print("Enter the eighteenth number: ");
   num_r = user_input.next();

   String num_s;
   System.out.print("Enter the nineteenth number: ");
   num_s = user_input.next();

   String num_t;
   System.out.print("Enter the twentieth number: ");
   num_t = user_input.next();

System.out.println(num_a + "s + " + num_b + "a + " + num_c + "f + " + num_d + "e = " + num_e);
System.out.println(num_f + "s + " + num_g + "a + " + num_h + "f + " + num_i + "e = " + num_j);
System.out.println(num_k + "s + " + num_l + "a + " + num_m + "f + " + num_n + "e = " + num_o);      
System.out.println(num_p + "s + " + num_q + "a + " + num_r + "f + " + num_s + "e = " + num_t);

System.out.println(num_a + "s + " + num_b + "a + " + num_c + "f + " + num_d + "[(" + num_t + " " + num_p + "s + " + num_q + "a " + num_r + "f) / " + num_s + "] =" + num_e);
System.out.println(num_f + "s + " + num_g + "a + " + num_h + "f + " + num_i + "[(" + num_t + " " + num_p + "s + " + num_q + "a " + num_r + "f) / " + num_s + "] =" + num_j);  
System.out.println(num_k + "s + " + num_l + "a + " + num_m + "f + " + num_n + "[(" + num_t + " " + num_p + "s + " + num_q + "a " + num_r + "f) / " + num_s + "] =" + num_o);

// THIS creates the fourth equation items/order to be substituted into the other first three equations.

int t = num_t;
int s = num_s;
int num_ts = (t / s);



num_ts = 
num_ps = (num_p / num_s);
num_qs = (num_q / num_s);
num_rs = (num_r / num_s);
// THIS is the Fourth equation being substituted into the First Equation
num_dts = (num_d * num_ts);
num_dps = (num_d * num_ps);
num_dqs = (num_d * num_qs);
num_drs = (num_d * num_rs);
// THIS is the Fourth equation being substituted into the Second Equation
num_its = (num_i * num_ts);
num_ips = (num_i * num_ps);
num_iqs = (num_i * num_qs);
num_irs = (num_i * num_rs);
// THIS is the fourth equation being substituted into the Third Equation
num_nts = (num_n * num_ts);
num_nps = (num_n * num_ps);
num_nqs = (num_n * num_qs);
num_nrs = (num_n * num_rs);

System.out.println(num_a + "s + " + num_b + "a + " + num_c + "f + " + num_dts + " " + num_dps + "s + " + num_dqs + "a " + num_drs + "f = " + num_e);
System.out.println(num_f + "s + " + num_g + "a + " + num_h + "f + " + num_its + " " + num_ips + "s + " + num_iqs + "a " + num_irs + "f = " + num_j);  
System.out.println(num_k + "s + " + num_l + "a + " + num_m + "f + " + num_nts + " " + num_nps + "s + " + num_nqs + "a " + num_nrs + "f = " + num_o);


 }



}
```

Comment: Think about this statement: `int t = num_t;` num_t here is a `String`.  You can't assign cross-type that way in Java.  Try using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Likewise with statements like `num_ps = (num_p / num_s);`, `num_p` and `num_s` are `String`s, you can't apply arithmetic operators to them like that.

Comment: *"Try using `Integer.parseInt()`"* And/or [`Scanner#hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) and [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--).

Comment: Also, you don't need 20 variables to hold 20 numbers.  You need to learn about arrays.

Comment: You also need to learn the concept of a minimal example.  This is way to much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add, subtract, divide, or multiply String variables. You have to make your variables into ints in order to do that. Also, you can use an array to hold your variables, since there is so many of them.

Answer (score 0):

`String`, `Integer`, `Float`, are not the same types. you can't apply operators like `/` or `*` on `String` for instance. `+` is special because it has a definition for `String`, which means *concatenate*.

Since you need to do some operations on the user inputs, you can read them directly as `int`:

```
System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
int num_a = user_input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
int num_b = user_input.nextInt();
```

Then you can do

```
int num_ab = a / b;
```

Note that if `a < b`, then `num_ab` will be `0`, since this is an `int`eger. You may want to do something like

```
float num_ab = (float)a / b;
```

---

Now, this code is quite tedious. If you accept to handle indices instead of letters for the variables, you can initialise them in a loop, e.g.

```
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    int index = 0;
    while (index < numbers.length) {
        System.out.println("Enter the "+(index+1)+"th number");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        numbers[index] = n;
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

And use the array of numbers

```
// arrays start at 0 
int num_ab = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
```

And if you want to be able to access the variables through names, you can define constants

```
static final int a = 0;
static final int b = 1;
static final int c = 2;
//...

int num_ab = numbers[a] / numbers[b];
```

---

But in your case, it may be handy to store initial variables **and** computed ones in some place where you can retrieve them for further computations:

```
// the store for all the variables and their value
static Map<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<>();

// the function to read in the store
static Integer var(String name) {
    return vars.get(name);
}
```

The store is initialised by a loop:

```
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    // The 20 variables...
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrst";
    for (char c : alpha.toCharArray()) {
        String varName = String.valueOf(c);
        System.out.println("Enter the value for "+ varName);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        vars.put(varName, n);
    }

    System.out.println(vars.toString());

    int num_ab = var("a")/var("b");

    // Store ab for further computation
    vars.put("ab", num_ab);
    System.out.println("ab is " + var("ab");
```